# docker volume create - set permissions

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running this on debian 9

I'm using `sudo docker volume create db` to create a volume I'm using in my `docker-compose.yml`. But I still get the error `db_1_d89b59353579 | mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied`.

How can I set permissions for the user using that volume. And how to get the user?

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql:z
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

I got an install.sh file where I run:

```
...
sudo docker volume create db

sudo docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Please share your docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile (if applicable) and the commands you run to build images and start containers/services.

Comment: @Mihai added the code

Comment: This exact example works for me on MacOS but without creating the volume and without the build command: You already create the volume inside the docker-compose and there is nothing to build since you  don;t have Dockerfile's. Can you please remove the volume and try again? Also I have to admit I don't know the volume flag ":z". What are you trying to achieve? In any case I ran the example with it and it worked

Comment: Note: the volume has no influence because it is not used anyway. Docker-compose creates and uses volumes with different names anyway. So probably the problem is the OS and the ":z" flag (maybe you can try without)?

Comment: @Mihai I already trier without it and get the same error. On unix.stackexchange I asked a similar question and was told "In your docker-compose.yml, you have defined a named volume db that is to be mounted to the db container. If you are not creating the db named volume before executing docker-compose up, then the /var/lib/mysql directory within the volume likely is being created with incorrect permissions as you are normally a privileged user when running docker-compose".

Comment: Look closely when the docker-compose up starts and you will see the name of the volume that is created. It is <current_folder>_db. This is especially to avoid conflicts with volumes created outside docker-compose.

Comment: What puzzles me is that /var/lib/mysql should not be created. It is already inside the image and is declared as a volume. Should only me mounted. So for some reason docker-compose tries to create it, which is weird. Can you try a volume like this instead: "./db:/var/lib/mysql". This should create a db folder in your current folder. You still haven't told me on which OS you are running so I hope it is a Linux like one ;)

Comment: I added the information in the question. I'm using debian 9 stretch

Comment: Welll, the error by mariadb is gone. But Nextcloud says `app_1_fcd4b1574a84 | [Wed May 15 08:47:31.996536 2019] [core:crit] [pid 29] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.19.0.1:52336] AH00529: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/' is executable, referer: http://localhost:8080/
`

Comment: looks like a similar issue. Can you use again a local directory and see if files are populated in there?

Comment: Wow, that worked! but how to do this on other dierctories, such as `nextcloud:/var/www/html` instead of `./mnt/data/nextcloud:/var/www/html` ?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use the docker volumes instead of the normal directories? The first one in your question is a volume and is completely maintained by docker. In the meantime I'll try to understand why the volume doesn't work

Comment: @Mihai I just pulled the code from the github Nextcloud project. At the first start it worked perfectly and I just want to understand what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193384/discussion-between-mihai-and-temp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to first change the mounts to local folders and see if that fixes your issue:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
...
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
...
    volumes:
      - ./nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

If that does then check that the volumes are correctly removed by `docker-compose down`. Run `docker volume ls`. If they still persist then remove them by hand and rerun your containers with the volumes.

Regarding the **difference between mounting to a volume (db:/var/lib/mysql) and mounting to a host path (./db:/var/lib/mysql)**:

In the first case it is a [volume managed by Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). It is meant for persistence but getting to the files is a bit more tricky. In the second case it is a [path on the host](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and it makes it a lot easier to retrieve persisted files. I recommend to run "docker-compose config" for both situations and see the difference in how docker-compose internally transforms the statement.

Comment: You could write what is the difference between `db:/var/lib/mysql:z` and `./db:/var/lib/mysql` (answer to this one is interesting IMHO and confuses a lot of docker users).

Comment: In the first case it is a volume managed by Docker. It is meant for persistence but getting to the files is a bit more tricky. In the second case it is a path on the host and it makes it a lot easier to retrieve persisted files. I recommend to run "docker-compose config" for both situations and see the difference in how docker-compose internally transforms the statement.